# PHP if prior to date echo this

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement

Trying to do a simple echo statement if prior to date except I'm only getting the else echo ...

```
<?php 
if (time() < strftime('2016-01-13 00:00:00'))
  {echo "You're early!";} 
else {
 echo "You're late!";}
?>
```

Little help. Thanks. Yes, I'm new to this.

Comment: Instead of `strftime` use `strtotime` to convert into time stamp!!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to convert date time stamp into unix timestamp (seconds since 01-01-1970).

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) but, we have another accurate method for this.

Use [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2016-01-13 00:00:00');
$timeStamp = $date->getTimestamp();
if (time() < $timeStamp) {
  echo "You're early!";
}
else {
  echo "You're late!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok. It works with just $date = new DateTime('2016-01-13 00:00:00'); Doesn't matter what time I enter for 00:00:00 ... just echoes according to the date. I'm in EST.